# SQL query to find count of ids for page_name with one value for page_title (multiple page_titles per page_name))

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table which includes date, page_name, page_title and ID. page_name is the unique identifier for the page but it may have many page_titles (as the title changes through the day). I'd like to get a count of the distinct IDs per page_name but only want one page_title per page_name. I'd like the page_title to be the title that has the highest count of IDs.

I've tried to do a join but it doesn't seem to give only one page_title...

When successful, I'd expect to get all page_names, ordered highest to lowest on the count of distinct id, each with one page_title (which is the most 'popular' page_title).

What I've tried:

```
SELECT a.page_name,
       a.page_title,
       COUNT(DISTINCT id)
FROM pages AS a
  LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT page_name,
                          page_title,
                          COUNT(DISTINCT id)
                   FROM pages
                   GROUP BY 1,
                            2
                   ORDER BY 3 DESC) AS b ON a.page_name = b.page_name
GROUP BY 1,
         2
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```

Sample Data

```
page_name   page_title       id
Page 1      First page       645
Page 1      First page2      898
Page 1      First page2      645
Page 2      Second page      746
Page 2      Second page3     746
Page 2      Second page2     434
Page 2      Second page4     345
Page 2      Second page4     333
Page 3      Third page2      777
Page 3      Third page       777
Page 3      Third page2      738
Page 3      Third page3      734
```

Expected result

```
page_name   page_title      count(distinct id)
Page 1      First page2     2
Page 2      Second page4    4
Page 3      Third page2     3
```

Comment: You could put a sample data and what you expect for result. So page_name has many page_title and page_title has many id?

Comment: Put some sample data in :) yep page_name has many page_titles and ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
  SELECT page_name,
         MIN(page_title),
         count_id
    FROM (
           SELECT page_name, 
                  page_title, 
                  COUNT(distinct id) count_id,
                  MAX(COUNT(distinct id)) over (PARTITION BY page_name) max_count
             FROM pages
         GROUP BY page_name, page_title
         ) pages2
   WHERE count_id = max_count
GROUP BY page_name, count_id
ORDER BY count_id DESC, page_name
```

Comment: I am still getting multiple page_titles with this, is there any way I can just get one page_title per page_name?

Comment: Maybe it happens because there are two or more page_title with the same count of distinct IDs and most popular at same time. So I changed a little bit the query to get only one most popular page title. Please, try again.